# MongoDB - Check property occurrence within an array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Below is the sample structure of my document. I have to find those documents where the "property1_int" occurrence in an array is less than 2. For example in document1, "property1_int" occurrence is 2 whereas in document2, "property1_int" occurrence is 1

```
    {//document1
    "_id" : NumberLong(1),
    "my_array" : [ 
        {
            "id" : 123,
            "name" : "Alice"
        },
        {
            "id" : 124,
            "name" : "Bob"
        },
        {
            "name" : "John"
        }
    ],
},
{//document2
    "_id" : NumberLong(2),
    "my_array" : [ 
        {
            "id" : 123,
            "name" : "Ana"
        },
        {
            "name" : "James"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Andy"
        }
    ],
}
```

I have tried this query db.collection.find({"my_array.id": $size: {$lt: 2}}) but it checking individual element property size instead of occurrence in an array

Answer (score 0):

I'll let you the query here and what I have done.

[query](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vd42HcZ6nG_)

First we unwind the array and we were left with only the documents that had the field we wanted.

Then we re group the documents and reform the my_array field with only the information we wanted.

The last step is to check how many documents with the target field are in the array. Since we have already filtered the ones we know contain it, we only have to check how many there are.
Checking whether index 1 exists or not will give us the answer.
For example:

["doc1", "doc2", "doc3"]

Here the array index 1 exists with the value "doc2", so this array has at least 2 documents.

["doc1"]

In this case index 1 does not exist so the array must have 0 or 1 documents.

**EDIT**

To get the whole document again we need some extra steps. Maybe there is a better way to achieve the same result, but here it is what i did.

[query 2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LmTi5qBwPvh)

The explanation of the added operations are the following:

Once we got the documents we wanted in the last query, we search for its id in the collection and store then in a new array field "all".

We unwind this array.

And finally we made this field the new root to obtain the expected result.

Comment: Unable to understand your last point. How it will return the documents that have that field less than 2 times?

Comment: @K142130MuhammadZaidKhan I updated the explanation of the last point. Hope it helps

Comment: It was not working fine. I only need documents where the occurrence is less than 2, but it was also giving me the documents where the occurrence is 2 or more. I have achieved this result with the find query but am unable to achieve that less than 2 condition.

Comment: Did you check my query? It works fine for me. What are you trying?

Comment: yes, I saw that, and write my query wrt your query. I have given my scenario exactly the same as my original one but I have given sample values here. Your query is also giving me occurrences which are 2 or more. I only need documents which contain occurrence of my property only less than 2 in a document

Comment: I understand what your desired output is. Could you update your question with real data examples or what are you trying?

Comment: Now, I want all documents where my_array have embedded documents whose ids are less than 2. Here in our example, it will only give us 2nd document as it has the occurrence of my_array.id < 2

Comment: I have run your playground, it's only returning one embedded document of 2nd document. I need whole 2nd document where my condition met.

Comment: @K142130MuhammadZaidKhan I think I  got what you needed now. I didn't know that you needed the whole document.